# Structure pages mvc + oop

Tags: php, object-oriented, mysql, mvc, pdo

I am developing a website and I want to use PDO and MVC.

Before, I was coding in procedural MySQL, but I'm starting to understand the object-oriented programming.

My problem is the following:

If I understand the MVC pattern, there are 3 parts

1. View (It's my Html)
2. Model (PHP requests)
3. Controller (Control and form validation)

Right?

I want to know if I have the right approach to MVC.

So, I put code that works and I try to change in MVC. (My test MVC is lower in the page.)

```
$db = new DbConnect();
$error = '';
if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])){
   if(empty($_POST['login']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
       $error = 'All fields required';
   }else{
       $db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_login = :login AND u_password = :password');
       $db->bind(':login', $_POST['login']);
       $db->bind(':password', md5(sha1($_POST['password'])));
       $row = $db->single();
       if($db->rowCount() > 0){
           echo 'I can save some informations by sessions';
           echo '<pre>';
           print_r($row);
           echo '</pre>';
       }else{
           $error .= 'Not find in the Data Base';
       }
   } 
}
if(!empty($error)){
    echo $error;
}
```

Here the html form:

```
<form action="login" method="post" name="login">
<label for="login">Login:
    <input type="text" name="login" id="login">
</label>
<label for="password">Mot de passe:
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
</label>
<input type="submit" name="login_submit" value="Se connecter">
```

Now I try to evolve towards the MVC model like this:

1. My Model called **model.login.php**:

```
class Auth extends DbConnect{
    protected $login;
    protected $password;
    protected $email;

    public function ConnectSecure(){
        if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])){
            CheckPostLogin();
            $this->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_login = :login AND u_password = :password');
            $this->bind(':login', $_POST['login']);
            $this->bind(':password', md5(sha1($_POST['password'])));
            $this->single();
            if($this->rowCount() > 0){
                echo 'OK and I put some informations by sessions';
            }else{
                echo 'No in DB or error combination user/password';
            }
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($result);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
}
```

2. My controller called **controller.login.php**:

```
require 'models/model.login.php';
function CheckPostLogin(){
    if(empty($_POST['login']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
        Message::ShowError('All fields required.');
        return false;
    }
}
```

3. My view has the same HTML code listed above.

I have also a global class that will handle static functions to display messages for error, success, etc. like this (just an example):

```
class Message{
    public static function ShowError($message){
        echo $message;
    }
}
```

I have another problem:

Inside my model, after the query, I check if I have some result. I think this part need go on the controller. Right? If yes, how can I do this properly?

I'm new to OOP. If you see any errors or discrepancies, your advice is welcome.

Comment: Simplified, the controller is the traffic agent that links the correct model(s) and view(s) together.

Answer (score 2):

> <sup>Well .. **you do not understand MVC design pattern**. You seem to got all three parts wrong. Since I am quite lazy person, I will just direct to some older posts of mine that might help you to deal with [handling pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208), some [initial studies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16356866/727208) for the subject, basics of [views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596704/727208), [model layer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208), some minor note on [controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13396866/727208). Also there is a bit about [access control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685039/727208) in context of MVC, that might be useful to you.</sup>

#### Now! To the code ...

**File:** *model.login.php*

- Model is not subtype of database connection (wel .. model is not even a class). This class is violating SRP <sup>[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), [[2]](http://tomdalling.com/wp-content/uploads/LSP.jpg), [[3]](http://docs.google.com/a/cleancoder.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0BwhCYaYDn8EgNzAzZjA5ZmItNjU3NS00MzQ5LTkwYjMtMDJhNDU5ZTM0MTlh&hl=en)</sup> .
- Aside from making a pointless wrapper for PDO, there is also a serious problem there: `md5(sha1( ... ))` should **NEVER** be used for hashing passwords. Please read the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4948393/727208) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16896216/727208) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16044003/727208) from @ircmaxell.

**File:** *controller.login.php*

- You should learn how to use autoloader. Start by reading the documentation about [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). Also I would recommend to look into what are [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) and how then can be used together with autoloading schemes.
- Don't us static method calls. Just because you wrap something in a `class` does not make it object-oriented (notice how it isn't called "class-oriented programming" .. there is a distinction). When used this way, your class acts only as namespace for your global-scope functions.

... the rest, IMHO, is covered in the linked posts above.